How To change active item's color in floating links or icon in wordpress
I m new to wordpress and using floating menu plugin to float some links (links to same page).. It is working fine anyways but there is no option to highlight the active link.. is there anyway to change active link's color or icon's icon..
my purpose is just to highlight the active item (by any possible way - background color change or link color change or icon color change even if text size change is fine )
link to the website in i working on Website
I have tried this with help of mozilla inspect tool.. tried many css solution available on stack overflow and others but no luck. Still could not find how to make current item active.. any help will be appreciated,

Look at the dev tools these floating menus have class: f12-floating-menu-6860 and icons are Fas icon with class fas; You can use these classes to change colors of icons ex: .f12-floating-menu-6860 .fas { color:red;}  should work.

how to change color when user clicked that... i can change color when hover too... but i m seeking solution to change when user click that link and that color should stay active till user click on another link.

you can try To style active link like this f12-floating-menu-6860 a:active. You can also use eventlistener for click to toggle classes on these links

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

How to paste whole plugin code here... I have explained the problem.. How to change color of visited floating item on wordpress site... You may be experienced but i am new so seeking help here..

You can add an event listener to each link in your floating menu that toggles a class on click. This will allow you to persist the active state across clicks.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.element-to-highlight a');

    menuItems.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Remove the 'active' class from all items
            menuItems.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));

            // Add the 'active' class to the clicked item
            this.classList.add('active');
        });
    });
});

Then write the CSS to highlight the link when it's active, for example:
.element-to-highlight a.active {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}


yes It is working.. its highlighting the text color and changes background of active link.. I was looking for such solution.. thanks
